# How to post a request with json data to an URL from python and get the response in json

Tags: python, api, pfx

How to post a request with json data to an URL using python and get the response in json. Need to use pfx file and password for the successful request

Comment: Looks like you forgot to post the code that you're having trouble with

Comment: `code` json_data = data

# Load the PFX file contents and passphrase
pfx_password = "mypassword"
with open(pfx_filename, 'rb') as pfx_file:
    pfx_content = pfx_file.read()

# Set the headers with the necessary content type
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

# Send the POST request with the JSON data in the body and the PFX certificate
response = requests.post(url, json=json_data, headers=headers, cert=(pfx_content, pfx_password))

# Print the response content
print(response.content)